# Difference between probability and possibilty

Tags: word-choice

I often get confused with the mentioned words as I am not a native English speaker and I don't know what they actually mean.

From [wordkinck](https://www.wordnik.com/words/probability),

> Possibility: The quality or condition of being probable
>
> Probability: The fact or state of being possible.

Which seems a paradox to me as the word is present on its own definition.

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/probability)

> Probability: The level of possibility of something happening or being true.
>
> Possibility: A chance that something may happen or be true.

So my questions are,

- What they mean literally?
- When and where to use them or not?

Comment: I think that Word Knock definition was a mistake, and that it has been corrected since you posted your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’d use **probability** as a quantifiable, mathematical term. If I spoke about probability, I might be talking about numerical odds or chances: e.g. one chance in six or even Bayesian probability. I don’t use possibility in that way, it is more qualitative.

One way to understand the more slight differences in common meaning is to consider the related words **impossible** and **improbable**. Sherlock Holmes said:

> "How often have I said to you that when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?"

From that, we can deduce:

Impossible - cannot be done

Improbable - unlikely to be done

Possible - can be done (but may be unlikely)

Probable - likely to be done (and likelihood can be measured mathematically)

Comment: Wow, excellent analogy. Thanks.